# Two separate fixed column headers with horizontal scrolling with CSS or JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed-header-tables

I'm trying to get two separate tables on the same page to have fixed headers that either have vertical scrolling content or "stick" to the top of the page when scrolling down.

The issue I'm running into is that one of the tables has horizontal scrolling content.

Here's what it looks like.  What I'd like to be fixed is the "JAPAN", "Customer" columns on the left and then the "Producer", "PR" & "Q" columns in the horizontal scrolling table.  Is this possible with CSS or even JQuery with how I have this setup?

Thanks.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7fnzxoq4/

Sample code from JSFiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" >
<div class="outerFixedColumn">
    <table class="fixedColumn">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="5">JAPAN</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Customer</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Sector</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            ...data...    
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div class="innerFixedColumn">
    <table class="fixedColumn scrollTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="centered" colspan="2">Producer 1</th>
                <th class="centered" colspan="2">Producer</th>
                <th class="centered" colspan="2">Producer</th>
                <th class="centered" colspan="2">Producer</th>
                <th class="centered" colspan="2">Producer</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <th class="centered">PR</th>
                  <th class="centered">Q</th>
                  <th class="centered">PR</th>
                  <th class="centered">Q</th>
                  <th class="centered">PR</th>
                  <th class="centered">Q</th>
                  <th class="centered">PR</th>
                  <th class="centered">Q</th>
                  <th class="centered">PR</th>
                  <th class="centered">Q</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            ...data...
        </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content .outerFixedColumn {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#content .innerFixedColumn {
  overflow: auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}

#content table.fixedColumn {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#content table.fixedColumn.scrollTable {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

#content table.fixedColumn th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 6px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #eeeeee;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

#content table.fixedColumn th.row {
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

#content table.fixedColumn td {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 6px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
}

#content table.fixedColumn th:first-child,
#content table.fixedColumn td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

#content table.fixedColumn.scrollTable.costs td {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of different ways to do that. The quick and dirty route is to use jQuery to adjust to relative position of your `thead` elements based on the scroll offset of the window. The problem with doing it this way is that you have to run the function on `$(window).scroll` which can be tiresome.

Here's the jQuery that you would need for it (*Keep in mind that you would have to make sure that `thead { position:relative; }` exists in your CSS*):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('thead').each(function(){
    $(this).css({'top':$(window).scrollTop()});
  });
});
```

It's a little laggy due to the additional calculations running for it to work in an iframe like that, but here's [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fnzxoq4/1/).

Comment: Thanks, I added `style="position:relative;"` to the `thead` elements of your JSFiddle but the headers don't remain fixed when scrolling.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I seem to have found the problem, I've used code similar to this before, but it was on elements that emulated a table layout. Firefox supports relative position of table elements (such as thead) but Chrome (and by extension - Safari) doesn't.